# Job not running on scheduled time - Kubernetes CronJob

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

Cronjobs are not running any job on its scheduled times, the jobs runs only when one or more cronjobs are deleted. Is there some cronjob number limit ? Where to get log messages of this problem?

EDIT:
I have exactly the same environment for development and production working perfectly, this only occurs in testing environment. This problem occurs daily and the workaround that I found was to delete one or more cronjobs to run what I want in that moment.

```html
---
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: rcj-homebroker-bolsa
  namespace: <KUBE_NAMESPACE>
spec:
  schedule: "0 14 * * 1-5"
  startingDeadlineSeconds: 600
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 5
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 5
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      activeDeadlineSeconds: 18000
      backoffLimit: 0
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            cronjob: rcj-homebroker-bolsa
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: rcj-homebroker-bolsa
            image: <DOCKER_TAG>
            command: ["/bin/bash"]
            args: ["./processBolsa.sh"]
            lifecycle:
              preStop:
                exec:
                  command:
                  - /bin/bash
                  - pre-stop.sh
```

Comment: please add your Cronjob manifest

Comment: I added the manifest to edited part.

Comment: Can you paste it as a file ?

Comment: Here It is @MaggieO:

Answer (score 2):

You set concurrency policy of [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) to `Forbid` which means, the cron job does not allow concurrent runs; if it is time for a new job run and the previous job run hasn't finished yet, the cron job skips the new job run.

Please set concurrency policy to `Allow` (default)- the cron job allows concurrently running jobs.

```
concurrencyPolicy: Allow
```

In exceptional situation use `Replace` flag:- if it is time for a new job run and the previous job run hasn't finished yet, the cron job replaces the currently running job run with a new job run.

Please take a look: [concurrency-policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#concurrency-policy).